# Code only processing last record not all of them

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I seem to have done something stupid but I can't see the wood for the trees.

I have the code below which steps though an array and divides groups of array elements into a string. It should iterate through this array 15 times and concatenate the output string. It only uses the data from the last record not the previous 14 in the output string.

Any thoughts most welcome.

```
//Now get the data for each individual
for ($i=$ind[0];$i<$ind[14];$i++){
    //echo $persons[$i]."<br>";
    //get the id
    if (strpos($persons[$i],"0 @")!==false){
        //if (strpos($record,"0 @I")!==false){
        $s = explode("@",$persons[$i]);
        for($k=1;$k<=count($s)-1;$k+=2){
            $data .= $s[$k]." ";
            $rec_id = "P ".$s[$k]."=";
        }
    }
    //get name
    if (strpos($persons[$i],"1 NAME")!==false){
        $n = str_replace('/','',$persons[$i]);
        $n = str_replace('1 NAME ','',$n);
        $data .= $n." ";
        $nt = $n;
        $pname = $n;
        //continue;
    }
    //Get Sex
    if (strpos($persons[$i],"1 SEX")!==false){
        $n = str_replace('1 SEX ','',$persons[$i]);
        $data .= $n." ";
        $sx = trim(strtolower($n));//."(".$row.",2):";
        $row++;
    }
    //Get Birth
    if (strpos($persons[$i],"1 BIRT")!==false){
        $bf = "y";//Has a birth fact
    }
    if ((strpos($persons[$i],"2 DATE")!==false) && $bf =="y"){
        $n = str_replace('2 DATE ','',$persons[$i]);
        $gotdate = "y";
        $data .= "B: ".$n." ";
        $b_date = "- B:".trim($n)." in ";
    }
    if (((strpos($persons[$i],"2 PLAC")!==false) && $bf =="y") && $gotdate =="y"){
        $n = str_replace('2 PLAC ', '', $persons[$i]);
        $data .= $n;
        $b_place = $n;
        if (empty($b_place)){$b_place =" ";};
        $bf = "n";
    }
    //Get Death
    if (strpos($persons[$i],"1 DEAT")!==false){
        $df = "y";//Has a death fact
    }
    if ((strpos($persons[$i],"2 DATE")!==false) && $df =="y"){
        $n = str_replace('2 DATE ','',$persons[$i]);
        $data .= "D: ".$n." ";
        if (empty($n)){$n=" ";};
        $d_date = "- D:".trim($n)." in ";
    }
    if ((strpos($persons[$i],"2 PLAC")!==false) && $df =="y") {
        $n = str_replace('2 PLAC ', '', $persons[$i]);
        $data .= $n . " <BR>";
        if (empty($n)){$n=" ";};
        $d_place = $n;
        $df = "n";
    }
}
if (empty($d_date)){$d_date=" ";};
if (empty($d_place)){$d_place=" ";};
//Now construct note field
$p_note ="= ".trim($pname)." was born ".substr($b_date,4).trim($b_place);
if (($d_date)!==" "){$p_note .=" and died ".substr($d_date,4).$d_place;}
//now write this record to string
$opf .= $rec_id.$sx."(".$row.",2):".$pname."\r\n".$b_date.$b_place."\r\n".$d_date.$d_place."\r\n".$p_note;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are ending your `for` statement a bit early...

```
       }
    }   // for is ending hear, move this to end of code
if (empty($d_date)){$d_date=" ";};
```

If you remove this } on the line indicated and put it at the end - you should process all of the records and not just the last one.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work I have already tried that. If I move it there I get data duplicated for each individual equal to the number of rows in the array for that individual along with a load of undefined variable errors.

Comment: If you mean that $data is repeated, then at the start of each loop set `$data = '';` this will stop the data being repeated for each person.

Comment: The $data variable is purely for my testing to display on screen. The $opf is the output string.

Comment: So do you have a loop outside this one which loops for each person?  If so then it would be useful to include that code as well.

Comment: No, this is the only loop.

Comment: OK - does `$data` give you the values your expecting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160930/discussion-between-colin-and-nigel-ren).

Answer (score 0):

With help from Nigel Ren (thank you very much) I needed an extra loop to process the data. So at the start I now have

```
for ( $j = 0; $j < 14; $j++ ) {
            for ($i = $ind[$j]; $i < $ind[$j+1]; $i++) {
```

And then I close the loop after the $opf variable line at the end of the code sample I originally posted.